# Angular Unit Test - Spies must be created in a before function or a spec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm getting the following error with my unit test. I can post the dashboard.service.js file if needed. The DashboardService.getHostDetails() returns a promise which I am trying to handle so I am trying to use spyOn().

```
Error: Spies must be created in a before function or a spec
```

dashboard.spec.js

```
import DashboardModule from './dashboard.module'
import DashboardService from './dashboard.service'

let dashboardService,
    _$translateProvider,
    _$q;

describe('DashboardService', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(DashboardModule));

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module({
      $translateProvider: jasmine.createSpyObj('$translateProvider',
        ['translations', 'preferredLanguage']
      ),
      $translate: jasmine.createSpyObj('$translate',
        ['use']
      )
    });
  })

  beforeEach(inject(($translateProvider, $q, DashboardService) => {
    _$translateProvider = $translateProvider;
    _$q = $q;

    dashboardService = DashboardService;
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    _$translateProvider.translations('en', {});
    _$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

    const promise = { then: jasmine.createSpy() };
    spyOn(dashboardService, 'getHostDetails').and.andReturn(promise);
  });

  it('should load the host information', () => {
    const hostDetails = dashboardService.getHostDetails();
    console.log(hostDetails);
    hostDetails.then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that mocha, chai and jasmine were all being used and conflicting. Using only jasmine now resolved the issue. Updated my `karma.conf.js` as a result.